# Oleh and chazak chazak

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, words, torah-reading

I've heard that, when receiving the last aliyah in a particular sefer, the oleh (one who received the aliyah) should not say “chazak, chazak…” because it is a berachah given to him by the congregation and is a sofeik (doubt) for the oleh. For this reason the ba’al koreih (reader of the Torah) should never get these aliyos.

Where is the source for this?

Comment: How could you possibly have an Aliyah that the reader can't get? What did they do before those jobs were separated?

Comment: @DoubleAA the custom saying of "chazak" at the end of the sefer probably came after the custom to split the roles of koreh and oleh. The earliest source I think is from the Maharam Mintz or someone of his era

Comment: @DoubleAA and this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%aa%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-chazak-chazak-venischazek-why doesn't ask for the earliest source

Comment: "it is a berachah given to him by the congregation and is a sofeik (doubt) for the oleh": you mean it's doubtful whether he should bless himself? or what? That's very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rivevos Ephraim 2:98](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&pgnum=163) and [4:80](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1535&pgnum=177) holds it's a hefsek and he should not be the Baal koreh for this aliah.

Halachicly speaking has a lot of sources on this, including this one.

See too [Shevet Halevi 7:202:2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1417&st=&pgnum=206) [Mishneh Halachos 7:22](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1879&pgnum=41) and [Beer Moshe 3:28:2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=888&st=&pgnum=41).