# When exactly do we say chazak chazak v'nitchazeik?

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service

At the end of each sefer we say *chazak chazak v'nitchazeik* -- leader first and then the congregation is what I've seen.  There is some uncertainty in my mostly-lay-led minyan about exactly when and how this is done, and since it only happens five times a year and I'm *mostly* with that minyan, I haven't had the opportunity to see how others do it.  I'll be the torah reader the next time this comes up (in two weeks), so I'd like to avoid the usual "um, do we do it now or...?" problem.

1. *Who* says this -- the *ba'al koreh*, the *oleh*, or the *sh'liach tzibbur*?
2. *When* is it said -- at the conclusion of the reading before the closing *b'racha*, or after the *b'racha*?

Comment: There are also variations in the wording. Some say "... v'nitchazak". Some I believe just say "Chazak!' once.

Comment: @DoubleAA or thrice

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%aa%d7%97%d7%96%d7%a7-chazak-chazak-venischazek-why

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69251

Answer (score 6):

From all the Ashkenazi shuls I have been to the custom is that the congregation rises right before the conclusion of the sefer(1 of the 5) and upon completion the congregation says chazak ,chazak,vnitchazek,and then the Baal koreh says it then the oleh says the bracha.

Comment: I thought that first the baal koreh says it, and after that the congregation does.

Comment: Never saw that,doesn't mean its not legitimate.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm getting confused between reading to myself and in shul...

Comment: +1. Note that (in my experience, anyway) this is done after the last of the regular _aliyos_ and not _maftir_.

Comment: @Scimonster I'm assuming that the correct way is for the cong. to say it first. The Torah reading is for the congregation. The Torah reader is, in a sense, a *shaliach*. It would be interesting to find out if this may have changed prior to a designated *Ba'al Kri'a*.