# Is the word "Nischazeik" or "Nischazak"?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk

When completing an entire book of the Torah (ex. *Bereishis*), it is customary in some communities to recite the words

> חזק חזק ונתחזק

which is translated out to "be strong, be strong, and let us be strengthened!"

In the Stone Chumash, the word נתחזק is vocalized as נִתְחַזֵּק, *nischazeik*. However, it has come to my attention that this may be incorrect, as the word is usually vocalized as נִתְחַזַּק, *nischazak*, as in Shmuel II 10:12, for example:

> חֲזַ֚ק וְ**נִתְחַזַּק֙** בְּעַד־עַמֵּ֔נוּ וּבְעַ֖ד עָרֵ֣י אֱלֹהֵ֑ינוּ וַֽיהֹוָ֔ה יַעֲשֶֹ֥ה הַטּ֖וֹב בְּעֵינָֽיו
>
> "'...Be strong, and let us strengthen ourselves on behalf of our people, and on behalf of the cities of our God: and [then] may God do what is good in his eyes.'"
>
> <sup>Translation from Judaica Press via [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15870/jewish/Chapter-10.htm).</sup>

**Is the *zayin* in the word properly vocalized with a *patach* or with a *tzeirei*?**

Comment: " it is customary to recite the words

חזק חזק ונתחזק" Only in some communities. In some others they say "חזק ונתחזק" and in some others they say "חזק חזק חזק"

Comment: This sounds similar to the debate in Kaddish between *Yitgadal* vs. *Yitgadel*.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92226/5275

Comment: Quite related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/yisgadal-or-yisgadel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75344/titkabbel-vs-titkabbal

Answer (score -4):

There is a difference between when the word ונתחזק is in middle of a Pasuk, then it is pronounced with פת"ח. However when it is at the end of a phrase, it is pronounced with a ציר"י.

הגר"ש דבליצקי שליט"א כותב דצ"ל ונתחזק בקמ"ץ, דבשמואל שם הוא באמצע הפסוק, ולכך הוא מנוקד בפת"ח. אבל כאן, זהו סיום, וצ"ל בקמ"ץ

תורה ודעת ו' גליון149

Comment: Can you support this assertion? Is there another usage of ונתחזק when it’s not connected to following words that would support your theory, or would this be better suited as a comment to the OP?

Comment: Wow your quote literally contradicts your summary

Comment: @DoubleAA - No contradiction at all. A קמ"ץ קטן is a ציר"י [see רש"י במדבר כ"ג /כ]. As a  medakdek, when Rav Divlitzky  refers to the ציר"י, he calls it a קמץ, as in קמץ קטן.

Comment: Are you joking? What evidence do you have that he wrote so obtusely?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Do you know anyone who says it with a קמץ? It's either a צירי or a פתח. So please explain why he says to say it with a קמץ. Also, there is nothing obtuse about writing the way the Rishonim write, just because nowadays we used different terminology.

Comment: Thee perchance may not knoweth any lad who doth useth a Kamatz, but presently thou hast learned of a solitary case: the hallowed congregation of R. Diblitsky. Oft thee shall avoid veering from the simplest understanding.